# Show hide paragraphs depends on div count

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to show is if `div id="div1"` then I need to hide all paragraphs except the paragraph that has an id of `para1`.

I can do it by CSS but the problem is I have more than 100 sets of divs. I want to know how can I do this via jQuery or any code.

```html
<div class="divclass" id="div1">
  <p id="para1" class="pclass">test</p>
  <p id="para2" class="pclass">test</p>
  <p id="para3" class="pclass">test</p>
  <p id="para4" class="pclass">test</p>
  <p id="para5" class="pclass">test</p>
</div>
<div class="divclass" id="div2">
  <p id="para1" class="pclass">test</p>
  <p id="para2" class="pclass">test</p>
  <p id="para3" class="pclass">test</p>
  <p id="para4" class="pclass">test</p>
  <p id="para5" class="pclass">test</p>
</div>
<div class="divclass" id="div3">
  <p id="para1" class="pclass">test</p>
  <p id="para2" class="pclass">test</p>
  <p id="para3" class="pclass">test</p>
  <p id="para4" class="pclass">test</p>
  <p id="para5" class="pclass">test</p>
</div>
.... up to 100+
```

Comment: Are you saying that you only want to show the first child `p` element in each `div`?

Comment: You can not have multiple elements with the same id.

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking. I am sure I am not the only one.

Comment: `$('.divclass p').not('#para1').hide();` but you should probably use css instead.

Comment: Here is the css you need `div > p {
  display: none;
}

div > p:first-child {
  display: block;
}`

Comment: What i am trying to do is for example:

div 1 = show paragraph 1 (hide paragraph 2 and 3)
div 2 = show paragraph 2 (hide paragraph 1 and 3)
div 3 = show paragraph 3 (hide paragraph 1 and 2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in above comment, you can not have multiple elements with same id. So you have to change id of your div's e.g.

```
<div class="divclass" id="div1">
  <p id="div1-para1" class="pclass">test</p>
  <p id="div1-para2" class="pclass">test</p>
  <p id="div1-para3" class="pclass">test</p>
</div>
<div class="divclass" id="div2">
  <p id="div2-para1" class="pclass">test</p>
  <p id="div2-para2" class="pclass">test</p>
</div>
```

After that you can do something like

```
$('ul.divclass>li:not(:first-child)').hide();
```

For detail refer fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b7yrvk6z/12/

Answer (score 0):

It's my understanding that you want to show the number of paragraphs based on the integer in the `id`.

**Based on your comments:** I modified the snippet (commented out one if and replaced it).  You actually want to show the indexed `p` associated with the `id`.

**Note:**

- I left the `id`'s on your paragraphs, technically this is incorrect and they are not necessary in the code sample below.
- I left the inner loop alone but it could be replaced by;

  ```
  $(elem).find("p").eq(count-1).show();
  ```

```js
$("div.divclass").each(function(idx, elem) {
  //get the count from the div's id
  let count = $(elem).attr("id").replace(/div/, ""); 
  $(elem).find("p").each(function(ii, iElem) {
    //if (ii < count) $(iElem).show();  //show that many
    if (ii == (count-1)) $(iElem).show();  //show that one
  });
});
```

```css
/*lets give the div's a border for clarity */
.divclass {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
/*hide all the paragraphs, we'll show the right ones at runtime*/
.divclass > p {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="divclass" id="div1">
  <p id="para1" class="pclass">this is number 1</p>
  <p id="para2" class="pclass">test</p>
  <p id="para3" class="pclass">test</p>
  <p id="para4" class="pclass">test</p>
  <p id="para5" class="pclass">test</p>
</div>
<div class="divclass" id="div2">
  <p id="para1" class="pclass">test</p>
  <p id="para2" class="pclass">this is number 2</p>
  <p id="para3" class="pclass">test</p>
  <p id="para4" class="pclass">test</p>
  <p id="para5" class="pclass">test</p>
</div>
<div class="divclass" id="div3">
  <p id="para1" class="pclass">test</p>
  <p id="para2" class="pclass">test</p>
  <p id="para3" class="pclass">this is number 3</p>
  <p id="para4" class="pclass">test</p>
  <p id="para5" class="pclass">test</p>
</div>
```

Comment: What i am trying to do is for example:

div 1 = show paragraph 1 (hide paragraph 2 and 3)
div 2 = show paragraph 2 (hide paragraph 1 and 3)
div 3 = show paragraph 3 (hide paragraph 1 and 2)

Comment: this is my css
    #d1 #p1,#d2 #p2,#d3 #p3,#d4 #p4,#d5 #p5,
#d6 #p6,#d7 #p7,#d8 #p8,#d9 #p9,#d10 #p10,
#d11 #p11,#d12 #p12,#d13 #p13,#d14 #p14,#d15 #p15,
#d16 #p16,#d17 #p17,#d18 #p18,#d19 #p19,#d20 #p20,
#d21 #p21,#d22 #p22,#d23 #p23,#d24 #p24,#d25 #p25,
#d26 #p26,#d27 #p27,#d28 #p28,#d29 #p29,#d30 #p30,
#d31 #p31,#d32 #p32,#d33 #p33,#d34 #p34,#d35 #p35,
#d36 #p36,#d37 #p37,#d38 #p38,#d39 #p39,#d40 #p40,
#d41 #p41,#d42 #p42,#d43 #p43,#d44 #p44,#d45 #p45,
#d46 #p46,#d47 #p47,#d48 #p48,#d49 #p49,#d50 #p50 ...... up to 100 {
 display: block;
}

Comment: @NoobDev I think this accomplishes your goal, with only one `p` to show you should eliminate the inner loop. I left it for readability//

Answer (score 0):

this will do it

```
$("#div1").children().each(function (){
    if($(this).attr("id") !== "para1")
        $(this).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of id attribute use the name attribute as id must be unique for better coding.

```js
function showHideDiv(){
for(var a=0;a<document.getElementsByTagName('div').length;a++){
var b = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[a].getElementsByTagName("*");
for(var c=0;c<b.length;c++){

if(a==c){
b[c].style.display='block';
}else{
b[c].style.display='none';
}
}
}
}
```

```html
<body onload="showHideDiv()">
<div class="divclass" id="div1">
  <p name="para1" class="pclass">test</p>
  <p name="para2" class="pclass">test</p>
  <p name="para3" class="pclass">test</p>
  <p name="para4" class="pclass">test</p>
  <p name="para5" class="pclass">test</p>
</div>
<div class="divclass" id="div2">
  <p name="para1" class="pclass">test</p>
  <p name="para2" class="pclass">test</p>
  <p name="para3" class="pclass">test</p>
  <p name="para4" class="pclass">test</p>
  <p name="para5" class="pclass">test</p>
</div>
<div class="divclass" id="div3">
  <p name="para1" class="pclass">test</p>
  <p name="para2" class="pclass">test</p>
  <p name="para3" class="pclass">test</p>
  <p name="para4" class="pclass">test</p>
  <p name="para5" class="pclass">test</p>
</div>
<div class="divclass" id="div4">
  <p name="para1" class="pclass">test</p>
  <p name="para2" class="pclass">test</p>
  <p name="para3" class="pclass">test</p>
  <p name="para4" class="pclass">test</p>
  <p name="para5" class="pclass">test</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So set a css rule that hides all the paragraphs and loop over to show the ones that you want visible.

```js
$(".divclass").each( function (i) {
  $(this).find("p").eq(i).addClass("show");
});
```

```css
.divclass > p {
  display: none;
}

p.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="divclass" id="div1">
  <p data-id="para1" class="pclass">test 1-1</p>
  <p data-id="para2" class="pclass">test 1-2</p>
  <p data-id="para3" class="pclass">test 1-3</p>
  <p data-id="para4" class="pclass">test 1-4</p>
  <p data-id="para5" class="pclass">test 1-5</p>
</div>
<div class="divclass" id="div2">
  <p data-id="para1" class="pclass">test 2-1</p>
  <p data-id="para2" class="pclass">test 2-2</p>
  <p data-id="para3" class="pclass">test 2-3</p>
  <p data-id="para4" class="pclass">test 2-4</p>
  <p data-id="para5" class="pclass">test 2-5</p>
</div>
<div class="divclass" id="div3">
  <p data-id="para1" class="pclass">test 3-1</p>
  <p data-id="para2" class="pclass">test 3-2</p>
  <p data-id="para3" class="pclass">test 3-3</p>
  <p data-id="para4" class="pclass">test 3-4</p>
  <p data-id="para5" class="pclass">test 3-5</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on comments I think I understand what you're going for.

For your HTML I'd change the paragraphs to use data attributes instead of IDs (IDs should all be unique meaning you can't have the ID para1 set to multiple elements)

```
<div class="divclass" id="div1">
  <p data-div="div1" class="pclass">Show Div 1</p>
  <p data-div="div2" class="pclass">test</p>
  <p data-div="div3" class="pclass">test</p>
  <p data-div="div4" class="pclass">test</p>
  <p data-div="div5" class="pclass">test</p>
</div>
<div class="divclass" id="div2">
  <p data-div="div1" class="pclass">test</p>
  <p data-div="div2" class="pclass">Show Div 2</p>
  <p data-div="div3" class="pclass">test</p>
  <p data-div="div4" class="pclass">test</p>
  <p data-div="div5" class="pclass">test</p>
</div>
<div class="divclass" id="div3">
  <p data-div="div1" class="pclass">test</p>
  <p data-div="div2" class="pclass">test</p>
  <p data-div="div3" class="pclass">Show Div 3</p>
  <p data-div="div4" class="pclass">test</p>
  <p data-div="div5" class="pclass">test</p>
</div>
```

Then grab your parent divs, and hide the ones that data does not match the parents ID

```
$("[id^=div]").each(function(){
 let this_id = $(this).attr('id') 
 $(this).children('[data-div!="' + this_id + '"]').hide()
})
```

https://codepen.io/Nahana/pen/BOvrwG